# В чем ошибка в предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь

Где ошибка в данном предложении: Большинство слушателей были очень внимательны. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совсем недавно было ошибкой:если подлежащим является собирательное имя сущ., обозначающее количество (большинство, множество, масса и т.д.), то сказуемое ставится, как правило, в ед. числе.Должно быть " Большинство слушателей было очень внимательно".

Но современная грамматика опирается в этом вопросе на смысл, поэтому допускается и множ. число, если имеется в виду не совокупность, а каждое действующее лицо.

Comment: Но я рассуждаю по правилу: При подлежащем, выраженном сочетанием собират-го существительного с одушевленным существительным (в нашем случае слушатели) в Родит. падеже множеств.числа сказуемое ставится в форме множ.числа. Получается, что в исходном предложении правильно. А в задании просят найти и исправить ошибку. Может, неправильно употреблена краткая форма прилагательного? Не понятно.

Comment: В задании не говорится об ошибке конкретно в этом предложении. В найденном мной задании так: "Упражнение 60. В каких предложениях нарушено согласование сказуемого с подле­жащим в числе?" (http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/2554426/page:2/ )

Comment: У меня другое задание: для учащегося вуза по предмету "Культура речи".

Comment: Нет, краткая форма уместна, имеется в виду согласование "большинство было внимательно". Эти задания были составлены давно, и никто их менять не собирается, а язык меняется. Сейчас допускается мн.ч., а недавно ещё не допускалось. Нормой считалось грамматическое согласование, а по смыслу - разговорное.